# How to transfer html view data or (Python) server data to Angular or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, google-app-engine, jinja2

I am programming a small web app on GAE using python webapp2 framework.

What I want to achieve is displaying server data to the html view through javascript or angularjs. Actually the app draws some graph using d3.js based on the server data. I know I can use $http.get to retrieve the data from server. But this way I need to create another page or handler. I am wondering if there is some way which I can do the below actions.

1. On the server python handler, retrieve the stored data, then passing to the jinja2 template values. Render the html.
2. Display some of the data on the html view via jinja2 template values.
3. (The missing part) How to pass the data to js from the python handler? Or how to pass the data to js from html view? I know two ways from the html view. One is using embedded javascript code.

   var data = {{serverData}};

The other is using hidden input form with angular data bind. Both of them not so nicely.

4.Compute the data and draw back to the view using d3js or other js lib.

Any idea about this? I reckon there might be some angular way to do this beautifully but didnt figure out.

Comment: Do you want to transfer HTML or do you want to transfer the data to create a graph on the client side? I would favor the latter, especially if you're already creating a client side JS app. Both are doable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already going to build an Angular app for the front-end, why not make the whole architecture RESTful? That way the front-end Angular app will be in charge of presentation and the server of just the data. You can pass data between the server and front-end through JSON which has the benefit of not needing to deal with html or templates in the back end? Angular already has Service and $http that can abstract away the two-way data binding, and using webapp2's RESTful nature you can make this happen fairly painlessly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think your suggestion is a better practice. I haven't thought it via the RESTful angle. Just came from the 'desktop' programming world.

Comment: It really makes sense once you start coding it. Many of the headaches are gone once you separate responsibilities. Passing HTML from server to client can be a major PITA -- specially on top of a framework like Angular. RESTful services via JSON are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 has a suggestion for this, and it is to pass the object into the context when the template is built. I'm not sure why you think this is ugly, or at least any uglier than using Jinja2 to template only HTML. Here is their suggestion (see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/):

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    doSomethingWith({{ user.username|tojson|safe }});
</script>
```

As others have suggested, you could use a RESTful service if you'd like, but without knowing more about your application, I'm not convinced that would make your code any cleaner. In my experience, embedding some data in the initial page load is a fairly common practice, and can simplify the rest of your application. No need to handle client async loading if you already have that data on the server on initial page load, and it doesn't slow down the initial request.

Comment: Really, this is a common practice? I don't have much serious web developing experience. I will try the RESTful way later. The embedded code just doesn't smell so good, but it is very convenient. Thank you.